# in asp.net core 2.1 there is any way to clear session state when user logout

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

i created asp.net core2.1 application and use session state to save current user permissions 
when user logout i need to remove session

i tried using

HttpContext.Session.Clear();
or

HttpContext.Session.Remove("QDesk");

but session not removed

when new user loged in session still have old value

can any one help me for this problem